# Audit failed authentication to domain

Tags: windows, authentication, active-directory

I want to get information about all failed login attempts on Active directory server.
I already changed these policies on AD controller:[image]

And disabled **Audit: Force Audit policy subcategory settings (Windows Vista or Later)** on client and controller machines.

After these actions I can see only success attempts login to Domain in Event Viewer(in Security page) from client machines on domain controller(failed attempts I can see only in Security log of client machine). 
What am I doing wrong? How can I see these attempts in security log of Active Directory controller as well?

Comment: You may find better help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), which is for server administration questions. Stack Overflow is just for programming questions.

Comment: Thank you, I'll ask it there